# Jquery string find with regex and replace with add one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

This is my string

```
<input name="e8[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e10[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e8[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e10[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e6[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e9[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e6[1][4]" value="" type="hidden">
```

I have to change all second array element with +1. it shoud be my output

```
<input name="e8[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e10[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e8[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e10[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e6[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e9[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="e6[1][5]" value="" type="hidden">
```

How I achieve this format with jquery or regexsolution. i make following regex to get last number of string how i work ahead

```
var patt1 = /(\d+)(?!.*\d)/;
```

Comment: why dont you use replace [4] by [5]

Comment: Regex doesn't convert your groups to any value other than string.  You'd need to convert to int to add +1 to all the values

Comment: how i pick 4 into string. it should be any number. but the number will be the same. ex in start it is 90 then all group it wil be the 90

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/LX3kZ/

Comment: not a fan of modifying html content using string operations... so here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/547Pc/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
var result = 'string'.replace(/\d+(?=\]")/g, function (match) {
    var newNum = Number(match) + 1; // 5
    return newNum;
});
console.log(result);// replaced second number in array with +1
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/q9vT6/1

Comment: is it work on all group? i want to chagne all second array element number with +1

Comment: @reena.sharam, check out the demo. Paste your html there and click the button

Comment: let me try this. how i console this result?

Comment: Yuppi its working . can you please tell me one more thing how i store the value in this case '5' in variable to other user?

Comment: you want to save 5 in a variable?

Comment: yes i want to same '5' in varibale it is a part of function i am working on it

Comment: See the edit. I've assigned a `newNum` variable, which you can use.